# How should I partition my drives?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, hardware, ubuntu

I have a new PC. It has an SSD with just 128GB of space, and an internal HDD with 1TB space.

I am about to install elementary OS as my primary OS and so I am wondering how I should partition the drives.

I am thinking I should install the OS onto the SSD, and have everything else on the larger internal drive.

But how do I do this during setup using the partitioning tool? Do I select the SSD for / (root) and select the other drive for the swap area and /Home?

Comment: I wouldn't use the slower drive for swap when you have an SSD nearby. Swap usage should be minimal, and wear and tear should be unnoticeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would prefer to keep the other(non-SSD) drive for Storage only. No system folders like Home etc. For installing the system(in the SSD) I would prefer create about 8 Gigs for swap space and install /(root) in the remaining space-this would automatically create the /home folder. 
128 Gigs of SSD is more than enough for a core install of Elementary OS and therefore creating a separate /home partition would not serve a lot of purpose. A separate /home partition is mostly necessary only when you are constantly installing new distros(and don't want user related /home data to be deleted-so you need to only format the /(root) partition in each new install) or if there are multiple distros side by side sharing the same /home partition(which BTW contains all the non-system user files) for convenience.
Since you are only going to use Elementary OS- I would not advise partitioning the SSD separately for /home-it's just extra effort for no good reason.
But if you **really** want to do so, I would suggest about 30 Gigs partition for the /(root), 8 for swap(as previously) and the rest for /home. All this from the SSD only. Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks cheeky. The only concern I have is that I will run out if space very quickly. For example, Visual Studio takes up 40GB on Windows, and ai have plenty of big programs that I'll need to install on eOS. All software gets stored in Home, right? I mean, other than system apps that are bundled with eOS?

Comment: Thanks @Cheeky, I went with your advice. I guess I can just choose where to install stuff when I run out of space. I am so glad to be free from Windows though. Too many bugs lately.

Comment: In most cases(almost all) software doesnt get bundled in /home. When you install an app from the software center-the app is installed in a specific folder deep in the /(root) directory with root permissions(for uninstalling it, permissions for opening and using it like any regular app are granted to all users-so you can open it and use it, but cant do superuser actions or uninstall it without the root password ). So if you are going to install lots of Linux apps - make sure that the /(root) partition is large enough.

Comment: I presume you are going to install Windows inside Virtualbox for certain Windows-specific apps like Visual Studio? If so, there is an option in Virtualbox to change where the new Virtual Drive created is Stored. So to save space in /home you can change where Windows is installed in Virtualbox(by default in /<user>/Virtualbox VMs to the 1TB non-SSD disk.

Comment: Yeah I'll be using virtualbox. Ah crud.. Installation completed, but it won't boot from the  SSD. It just keeps taking me back to BIOS.

Comment: Did you disable SecureBoot? Did you change the BIOS mode to Legacy instead of UEFI(makes it much more hassle-free)?

Comment: Also, you may try this...(found it in another forum) "Enter BIOS (while booting your PC, press either F1/F2/DEL/ESC, or whichever button opens BIOS on your system). Now search for something similar to "Boot Menu" and select it. Now select the SSD as primary boot device." Basically, select the SSD for booting-the BIOS may be automatically booting to the HDD)

Comment: I did yeah :( I tried booting from every drive, but neither of them will boot. Just goes straight to BIOS. DVD drive with OS on it still boots though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27146/discussion-between-cheekyngeeky-and-se13013).

Comment: Hmmm... Try asking another question regarding this specific problem. I don't seem to know the solution.

Comment: Sorry cheeky, I tried going into chat and saw your messages but it keeps taking me to the login page. While searching for a solution I realised that I am having this issue with all Ubuntu based distributions that I use. I've never had this issue before, but then again, I've never put Linux on this new PC either.

Comment: To answer your question from chat, the PC is only a couple months old.

Comment: It seems to be a new Ubuntu and new ElementaryOS issue. I just successfully installed ChaletOS and it is absolutely beautiful. Works perfectly... Except that for some reason it won't connect to any network (internet). I'm guessing the issue here is that Ubuntu doesn't have drivers for my new PC s wireless card?

Comment: Hmmm... ChaletOS... I should try that out sometime. Also, if you are still trying then try installing OpenSUSE or Fedora. Maybe the kernel version is quite old in ChaletOS (can be checked by a quick uname -r in the terminal) or maybe WiFi drivers are not  yet available for your hardware. So I would suggest doing a Google search for your WiFi hardware and see if solutions exist. Or, in the worst case scenario- if you have an Android, you can use it as a USB Tether to the laptop to connect to the WiFi.

Comment: Word of advise. - Do NOT try creating LiveUSB for OpenSUSE or Fedora using Unetbootin. For them, methods are different- a Google simple search will reveal a lot. (Yes, there is a lot of Googling for relatively new guys but its worth it)

Comment: Yeah, just tried that. Tried Bluetooth hotspot but even though the PC pairs and connects no internet. Also tried USB tethering... No luck there either. And, obviously, WiFi hotspot not working. Sigh... I try to get away from Windows... But all I get is more problems lol. I do have a macbook pro. But 98% of all descent apps aren't compatible with it. Not to mention using osx just doesn't "feel right"

Comment: Tried installing Linux side by side OSX on your Mac book? I think it would have a much better support than a new Windows laptop.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help by the way :) gonna try fedora now. Then open suse.

Comment: Best of Luck. :D Any problem...try hitting me(or someone with better points :P)/up on chat.

Comment: Kk thanks :D All of this has made me feel like playing some games... Which are on Windows lol. Trying... To... Resist.... :P

Comment: Ha ha. True. That was the one thing that kept me dual booting Windows for a long time as well. Keep trying. It's hard but not impossible. You might even dual-boot if you cant resist your delicious games. :)

Comment: Also...I have a rather quirky suggestion also...but has worked for me a lot of times. If you want to, you can install Linux on an **external pendrive or hard drive** taking care to install the bootloader there only and not in the computer's HDD/SSD. This way, anytime you want to use Linux, just plug in the drive and boot up the laptop.

Comment: Hey that's a good idea! Oh... Hold on a sec... I just remembered. Lol. I have an external USB WiFi adapter in my drawer. LOL. ;-( Damn me and my crappy memory... I know it works too cause I used to use it with elementary OS. Sigh. Now I have to format my HDD, then burn elementary ISO to USB again then repartition and install it again. This has been a long eight hours lol. At least you've been here and made it more fun lol

Comment: Also, here's a 9gag joke - Every slice of bread...is a sad story of wheat that couldn't become beer.

Comment: Also, check [this](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?71429-Desperate-to-get-Linux-properly-up-and-running-on-my-Asus-ROG-G20AJ) out.

Comment: Ha-ha its all good :-) I'm still trying to get that joke lol.

Comment: Great job! Welcome to the world of Linux- where the opportunities are endless and where I have a girlfriend. :( #lol #welcome2linux

Comment: I've been pinged because this comment thread is rather long. Could all future comments please be _really_ relevant to the answer or be posted in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25374/elementary-os